# How to Output the Field Values in Zapier

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am new to Zapier and writing JavaSctipt. I tried to use a BMI script that I found with Zapier to start learning how to use the code in association with apps but when I test it in Zapier it returns this error:

**We had trouble sending your test though. Please try again. Error: 
Error: You did not define `output`! Try `output = {id: 1, hello: "world"};`**

```
// Calculate BMI
var calculateBmi = function calculateBmi() {
    var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
    var height = document.bmiForm.height.value
    if (weight > 0 && height > 0) {
        var finalBmi = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100)
        document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
        if (finalBmi < 18.5) {
            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Você está muito magro."
        }
        if (finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25) {
            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Você está saudável."
        }
        if (finalBmi > 25) {
            document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Você está com sobrepeso."
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("Por favor preencha os dados corretamente")
    }
}
//-->
```

I'd really appreciate if someone can teach me what I need to do to export the results without errors or how I need to change my code to solve the this.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

Your issue is that you've defined a function, but never did anything with it!

If you look at the examples [here](https://zapier.com/help/code/#introductory-examples), each either calls `return` or sets the `output` variable to something, both of which get results outside of the Zapier function.

Another note is that neither `document` nor `alert` are available in Node.js (those are for browsers). You'll want to use map in those values from an earlier step (however that input happens).

At the bottom of your code, you'll want to call `calculateBmi(inputData.height, inputData.weight)` (once those values are correctly [mapped](https://zapier.com/help/creating-zap/#set-up-action-template) in).

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!